# Extract regex internal values in Java

Tags: java, regex

Given this text:

```
$F{abc} and $F{def}
```

I need to get

```
abc and def
```

For that, I would use this regex to find the values `\$F\{\w*\}` but I need to get what's represented by `w*`:

```
str.replaceAll("\\$F\{\\w*\\}", "??" );
```

Is this doable with a Java function or I need to write the routine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the text in a group:

```java
str = str.replaceAll("\\$F\\{(\\w*)}", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

## Update

I didn't read your question completely. Thanks to [The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63361826/extract-regex-internal-values-in-java/63362108#comment112041859_63362108) for pointing it out. Given below is the code for the expected output, `abc and def`

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "$F{abc} and $F{def}";
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\$F\\{(\\w*)\\}", "$1"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
abc and def
```

All you need to do is to replace the given string with the capturing group(1). The explanation in the original answer is still valid for this update.

## Original answer:

You can use the regex, `(\$F\{)(\w*)(\})` and replace the capturing group(2) with `??` and preserve the capturing group(1) and the capturing group(3) as shown below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "$F{abc} and $F{def}";
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(\\$F\\{)(\\w*)(\\})", "$1??$3"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
$F{??} and $F{??}
```

Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/m2u4Pw/1) for an illustration of all the [capturing groups](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) in the regex, `(\$F\{)(\w*)(\})`.

Answer (score -1):

One way is to use the regex `(\\$F\\{)|(\\})` you can both remove the `"$F{"` and `"}"` parts using `replaceAll()`:

```
String str = "$F{abc} and $F{def}";
str = str.replaceAll("(\\$F\\{)|(\\})", "");
```

About regex:

- `(\\$F\\{)` : 1. group `"$F{"`
- `|` : OR
- `(\\})` : 2. group `"}"`

Other way is to use a capture group reference in the replacement parameter. `$1` stands for the capture group `(\\w*)` that corresponds to `abc` and `def`

```
String str = "$F{abc} and $F{def}";
str = str.replaceAll("\\$F\\{(\\w*)\\}", "$1" );
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
abc and def
```

Comment: Why not have only one group?